# Proving continuity of $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Let $I=[0,1]$. Let $Q=I\times I$. Define $f:Q \to \mathbb{R}$ by letting $f(x,y)=1/q$ if $y$ is rational and $x=p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers with no common factor; let $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

I'm having some trouble showing $f$ is continuous when $x$ or $y$ is irrational. Have already proved discontinuity when $x,y$ are both rational.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, it looks like your function is discontinuous whenever $x =p/q$ is rational, even if $y$ is irrational.  In this case any ball around the point $(p/q, y)$ will contain points with irrational coordinates and points of the form $(p/q, y')$ with $y'$ also rational.  Thus, $f$ takes on the values $0, 1/q$ no matter how small the neighborhood, meaning that it is discontinuous at $(p/q, y)$.

If $x$ is irrational, then the function is continuous.  For any $\epsilon >0$ there are only finitely many values $p/q$ in the unit interval such that $1/q \ge \epsilon$.  If you choose your neighborhood small enough to avoid those $x$-values, then $f(x)< \epsilon$ in that neighborhood.